# Golang gorilla mux routes from class or file

Tags: go, gorilla

I'm playing around with gorilla mux and would like to set all of the application routes in a file so they don't fill up the main file with a bunch of routes.  Ideally I would like to have the optional ability to even pull the routes  from a database too.

Is gorilla mux the right package to use for this or is there something else to look at?  Is this something that can be done?

Comment: gorilla mux cannot do this on it's own. there's no reason though you have to put the routes in the main file.

Comment: I kinda figured that, do you know if there is any libs that have already been written to handle this, so I don't waste time trying to re-create the wheel?

Comment: I haven't seen any. A basic mapping wouldn't be hard to do, I'll put in an answer for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gorilla mux doesn't do this, and it's not common for routing libraries in Go, since it's statically typed and compiled language.

If you have a simple 1:1 mapping of handlers, you can do this fairly easily:

```
// register the handlers or handler_funcs by name in a map:
handlerMap := make(map[string]*http.Handler)
// OR
handlerFuncMap := make(map[string]func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request))

handlerMap["myHandler"] = myHandler

// now you can iterate over you config values and assign them to a router
for path, handler := range routes {
    myRouter.Handler(path, handlerMap[handler])
}
```

Comment: Thanks @JimB nice to have examples in case others search for similar stuff and nice explination on why it's not common place in go.